# ng-repeat doesnt loop thru my array

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, arrays, angularjs-ng-repeat

Hey everybody can somebody please give me a clue what im doing wrong here?

I trying to build a wrapper where every element in my array gets a  and a id 
But when i loop thru my real array i only get a error with the text: Error: [ngRepeat:dupes] ...
With a fake array i made it works perfect.

MY HTML:

```
    <div class="translaterBox">
        <span ng-repeat="person in persons" id="{{person}}">
            {{person + " "}}
        </span>

        <span ng-repeat="text in textWords" id="{{text}}">
            {{text + " "}}
        </span>
    </div>
```

MY SCRIPT

```
var app = angular.module('splitScreenApp', []);
app.controller('splitCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.translatetText = "Translate Here";

    $http.get("getContent.php")
        .then(function (response) {
            var content = response.data.content;
            $scope.content = content;

            function splitContentToWords() {
                var text;
                for(var i = 0; i <= content.length;i++ ){
                    if(content[i].text){
                        var text = content[i].text;
                    }
                    return text.split(' ');
                }

            }
            $scope.persons = [
                'Jack',
                'Jill',
                'Tom',
                'Harvey'
            ];
            $scope.textWords = splitContentToWords();
            console.log($scope.textWords);
            console.log($scope.persons);
        });
});
```

Thank you really much for your help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you get an error about dupes from Angular, it is because there are duplicate keys.  You can solve this by using `track by` as seen in [the documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/ngRepeat/dupes).

Try changing your `ng-repeat` to:

```
<span ng-repeat="person in persons track by $index" id="{{person}}">
<span ng-repeat="text in textWords track by $index" id="{{text}}">
```

Comment: Thank you really much! 
I have to say i still dont understand where i have a duplicated key